# Waiting for redirect in cypress?

Tags: automation, xmlhttprequest, cypress

I am testing a shop website that uses Bamboora as a way to test its order flow. So what I could do no problem is wait for Bamboora page to load, what I can't seam to figure out how to do is wait for Bamboora to send an XHR request and to redirect back to the shop so the shop could display "order completed".

This is code for what to do when I click the button that leads me to Bamboora.(https://www.bambora.com/)

```html
cy //confirmation before bambora
            .get('.sticky-bottom')
            .find('.innerwrapper-checkout-footer')
            .find('.v-btn')
            .click()
            .wait(6000)
```

On the page I need to wait till Bamboora confirms it and finishes the payment and that lasts for a maximum of 6-7 seconds when manually testing.

[image]

This is my attempt to make the redirect back to the shop site possible:

```html
    cy
        .get('.credit-card-form__removeText___1PUtd')
        .click()
    cy
        .get('.buttons__debugContainerButton___2FwvW')
        .eq('0')
        .click()
    cy
        .get('.payment-card-start__payButton___3NC_4')
        .click()

    cy
        .request('https://t-carlsjrapp.dsgapps.dk/pending-order')
```

Comment: Readers want to help you, but I don't imagine they can assist based on such minimal detail. Are you working on the payment phase of an order? Is that mocked out or calling a test payment service? Can you show any code/config so that readers can see what you are doing?

Comment: Yes I am testing the payment phase of the order, test should show if our website can connect with bamboora properlly and it is also testing some basic functionality of the shop.It is calling a test payment service (Bamboora), I have added code in the post now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that Bambora is loaded in an iFrame. I found this article to [work with iFrames in Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress/).

I haven't tested this, though.